Nifi SplitText split file with 2 records to infinity files
The configuration of my SplitText is:

The task is to split one csv file:
 id;description
 "1234";"The latitude is 12324.24"
 "2345";"12324.24 this value"

on 2 files:
 id;description
 "1234";"The latitude is 12324.24"

and
 id;description
 "2345";12324.24 this value"

But it returns 100000 and more duplicated files!
What am I doing wrong?

worked fine for me just now. I just copied your 3 line text file into a GenerateFlowFile processor's Custom Text field and all worked as expected.  I have two separate FFs each with the same header row and a different row at the bottom.  Tried it again duplicating rows 2 & 3 from the original 3 line file and I got the expected 4 FFs with content as expected. MAYBE you are processing that original file over and over (i.e. on my GenerateFlowFile I'm "Running Once" and NOT "Starting" it as that would create the problem you are experiencing (very fas, too).
